# What is this character ` called?

Tags: c, linux, bash, command-line, gtk

I never noticed the character ` (the one in the same key as tilde ~). There is another single quote character ' in the same key as ". I see that the characters ` and ' aren't interchangeable whereas ' and " are. 
I spent a lot of time due to that when compiling GTK programs. It gave error (file not found), and finally figured out that its not a single quote.
What is the purpose of this ` character and when is it (or when should it) be used?
Thanks.

Comment: The backtick can be used on stackoverflow to do inline (as well as in comments where there are no newlines) code, looking `something like this`. The way that it is used is dependent on the context of the use. Different contexts (languages, sites, etc) treat it differently, depending on the syntax of the context.

Comment: Single quotes and double quotes are **not** interchangeable, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Comment: @Reese Moore: +1 Yes, I noted that, so I had to escape it using "\".

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: But I think we use it interchangeably to represent strings in programming.

Comment: There are very few programming languages where `"` and `'` are interchangeable. In most, their meaning is very different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's typically called a "[backtick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)", and in bash, it is used for [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) (although the `$(cmd)` construct is usually preferred due to easier nesting).

Comment: Oh! Right, it takes the output from the one written inside that backtick and feeds into gcc. Another alternative I have used is $() and we write it ones inside the bracket. But is there any other purpose for the backtick character. Like in normal programming, instead of bash commands?

Comment: What language are you programming in? Different languages have different syntax and will therefore use different characters to mean different things.

Comment: @Reese Moore I'm using C (GTK+ 2.0) and encountered this when compiling using the pkg-config which has to be wrapped in that backtick. I instead used single quote & made my life miserable. But after a long time, I accidentally noticed it. I don't think C is using backtick any where.

Answer (score 4):

` is known variously known as a backtick, or grave accent (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).

In UNIX shells, as well as some scripting languages (Ruby, Perl...), it introduces some input to be executed in a subshell.  In C and C++, it has no special purpose but can be inserted as a character literal, or part of a string literal.  One reason it's not used for something more interested in the extremely wide portability of the languages spans machines where the character can't be expected to be on the keyboards, and may not display very differently from the single-right-quote "'" on screen and printouts, making for extremely hard-to-see bugs.

In some word-processing and similar application programs, typing a backtick will insert a single left quote character "‘".  Commonly keyboard input software will allow a user to type say "`e" in order to enter the character "è", or "`a` for "à" etc, as used in some languages' alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

I call it a "grave", as in a [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, it's used to surround identifiers when they might otherwise be ambiguous (such as using a reserved word as a table or column name). There are going to be lots of different uses of that character in lots of different pieces of software, just as there are for the other keys on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In a few languages, including PHP, Perl, and i think Ruby, backticks execute shell commands.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

The SQL thing mentioned is another use, which unfortunately I am well aware of because of co-workers who decided 'Desc' was a good name for a field